# Python override metaclass set attribute

Tags: python, class, overriding

Suppose I have a class:

```
class ABC:
    pass
```

And I do:

```
ABC.x = 123
```

This does not give me an error, even though I haven't created an object. Which of the `__func__` methods is being called, and how do I override it?

Comment: You're setting the attribute on the class object.  So `__setattr__` is called, but it's called on the metaclass.  Look up metaclasses to get an idea of what you're in for.

Comment: @BrenBarn thanks for the advice, I shall do that soon. However, to solve my immediate problem, do you mind submitting an answer? :)

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @BrenBarn Python3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a metaclass and override `__setattr__` there, then make your class use that metaclass.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, attrs):
        return super().__new__(meta, name, bases, attrs)

    def __setattr__(cls, attr, value):
        print("I am setting {}.{} = {}".format(cls.__name__, attr, value))
        return super().__setattr__(attr, value)

class Foo(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

Then:

```
>>> Foo.blah = 2
I am setting Foo.blah = 2
>>> Foo.blah
2
```